# Count Table 2 entities with reference to the UID in Table 1

Tags: php, mysql, reference, uniqueidentifier

I am trying find out the count of certain entries in one table with reference to the ID in another. Unfortunately I do not have the expertise to actually find the solution as I am quite new to PHP. Please refer below as I assume that will be more clear than me explaining it:

TABLE 1: (repeating table) (this is how it should look on a webpage)

```
Unique ID | product name | Bid Count | Min Bid
-------------------------------------------------
01        | Product A    |   (4)     |    $1000  
02        | Product B    |   (6)     |    $500
```

Table 2:(this 2nd table collects the bids from buyers but the unique ID is same as Table 1)

```
-------------------------------------------------
Unique ID | product name | Bid ($) 
-------------------------------------------------
01        | Product A    |  $2000  
01        | Product A    |  $1500  
01        | Product A    |  $1200  
01        | Product A    |  $1000  <<Lowest Bid | 4 bids count >>
--------------------------------------------------
02        | Product B    |  $1500
02        | Product B    |  $1000
02        | Product B    |  $700
02        | Product B    |  $800
02        | Product B    |  $600
02        | Product B    |  $500  <<Lowest Bid | 6 bids count >>
```

Please help with this challenge

Comment: So your table1 has only 2 fields `uniqueid and product_name` and you want to display bid count and min bid from the table2 linked by `uniqueid` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following -

```
mysql> create table table1 (id int, product_name varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into table1 values (1,'Prod A'),(2,'Prod B');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create table table2 (id int, bid int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into table2 values (1,2000),(1,1500),(1,1200),(1,1000),(2,1500),(2,1000),(2,700),(2,800),(2,600),(2,500);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from table1;
+------+--------------+
| id   | product_name |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | Prod A       |
|    2 | Prod B       |
+------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table2;
+------+------+
| id   | bid  |
+------+------+
|    1 | 2000 |
|    1 | 1500 |
|    1 | 1200 |
|    1 | 1000 |
|    2 | 1500 |
|    2 | 1000 |
|    2 |  700 |
|    2 |  800 |
|    2 |  600 |
|    2 |  500 |
+------+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now you can get the desired result using `join` and aggregate function `count`,`min` and finally `group by`

```
select t1.id , 
t1.product_name, 
count(t2.id) as `Bid Count`,
min(t2.bid) as `Min Bid` 
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
group by t1.id ;
```

Comment: Thanks Abhik, it was really helpful. However, I am still facing one problem. When I use the codes in a repeating table, it does not give the value of each unique ID, it rather shows value of first id in each row. Can you help me with this